# Jointjs tree layout connect leaf nodes to a single node

Tags: javascript, typescript, jointjs

I am new to Jointjs and I need to create a graph structure like this,

[image: sample]

I tried to create a tree structure and when connect the leaf nodes to a single node it doesn't look very clean like the tree structure.

[image]

I have multiple levels of this kind of graphs and this is just a one level screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone get into this question, the answer is you should use directed graph instead of tree layout.